# using logarithm in where clause with sqlite and pandas

Tags: sqlite, pandas, where-clause

I am trying to get a subset of a table based on the logarithm of one of the column values using the `pandas` package in Python2.7. The naive and simple approach is this:

```
testdb = sqldf('SELECT col_name from full_db WHERE log(col_name) < X,locals())
```

but this returns no records. It doesn't throw any error, just returns an empty DataFrame.

I can do other mathematical operations. For example, simple multiplication works just fine:

```
testdb = sqldf('SELECT col_name from full_db WHERE col_name*col_name < Y,locals())
```

returns the appropriate subset.

Can I not use function calls in a where clause?

EDIT: abs() works, but sqrt() doesn't. I'm sure my condition should be picking out a nonzero number of rows...

Some more info:

```
testdb = sqldf('SELECT duration_us, abs(duration_us), 300 from eventsdb',locals())

>>>      duration_us  abs(duration_us)  300
   0           24.24             24.24  300
   1           22.56             22.56  300
   2           21.84             21.84  300
   3           22.56             22.56  300
   4           21.36             21.36  300
   5           21.12             21.12  300
   6           24.96             24.96  300
   7           23.04             23.04  300
   8           31.68             31.68  300
   9           30.00             30.00  300
   10          26.64             26.64  300

testdb = sqldf('SELECT duration_us, log(duration_us), 1.5 from eventsdb',locals())

>>> None
```

Comment: what does `select col_name, log(col_name), X from full_db` look like? and what datatypes are involved?

Comment: @Alex K. Also returns None. Maybe I just can't use functions in SQL calls within sqldf()? But abs() works...

Comment: I edited with some more info about your question with an example of a function that works as well.

Comment: See [core functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

Comment: Ah, So SQLite is simply a minimal implementation which does not define log?